# getting httparty undefined method `code' for #<Hash:0x007ff3625a4800> in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, httparty, exotel-api

I am writing specs for my first gem. But i am stuck with this weird error.
code for my rspec is

```
describe '#success' do
    let(:resp) { {"TwilioResponse"=>{"SMSMessage"=>{"Sid"=>"0d1c0cbfb2b5e8f97dddb4479bdbbc6a", "AccountSid"=>"exotel_sid", "From"=>"/exotel_sid", "To"=>"1234", "DateCreated"=>"2016-07-18 15:35:29", "DateUpdated"=>"2016-07-18 15:35:29", "DateSent"=>nil, "Body"=>"test sms", "Direction"=>"outbound-api", "Uri"=>"/v1/Accounts/exotel_sid/Sms/Messages/0d1c0cbfb2b5e8f97dddb4479bdbbc6a", "ApiVersion"=>nil, "Price"=>nil, "Status"=>"queued"}}} }
    before{ allow(Generator::Exotel).to receive(:post).with("/#{Generator::configuration.sid}/Sms/send", 
      {:body => {:To => 1234, :Body => 'test sms'},:basic_auth=>{:username=>"#{Generator::configuration.sid}", :password=>"#{Generator::configuration.token}"}}).and_return(resp) }

    it 'returns response object' do  
      response = Generator::Exotel.send(:to => 1234, :body => "test sms")
      expect(response).to eq ({"Status"=>200, "Message"=>"Success"})
    end
  end
```

when i run `rspec` i am getting this error

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `code' for #<Hash:0x007ff3625a4800>
```

This is where my `response.code` is being called

```
def handle_response(response)
  response_base = response['TwilioResponse']
  if response_base.include?('RestException')
    response_base['RestException']
  else
    {"Status" => response.code, "Message" => "Success" }
  end
end
```

I know httparty creates a `response` object for request and returns response code. But i am not getting how do i create a dummy `response_code`
so that my test case pass. It's nearly 2 days since i am stuck here. Anyone help please. I am really new to ruby and for first time writing spec. Any help will be appreciated.

**Update** - result for `response.inspect`

`> Generator::Exotel.send(:to => 9030435595, :body => 'jsdhgjkdfg')`

it returns following response

```
> #<HTTParty::Response:0x7fb8c02f93d0 parsed_response={"TwilioResponse"=>{"SMSMessage"=>{"Sid"=>"d6ee0650072c82941ad2f06746d14ab4", "AccountSid"=>"sinscary", "From"=>"/sinscary", "To"=>"9030435595", "DateCreated"=>"2016-07-21 19:56:07", "DateUpdated"=>"2016-07-21 19:56:07", "DateSent"=>nil, "Body"=>"jsdhgjkdfg", "Direction"=>"outbound-api", "Uri"=>"/v1/Accounts/sinscary/Sms/Messages/d6ee0650072c82941ad2f06746d14ab4", "ApiVersion"=>nil, "Price"=>nil, "Status"=>"queued"}}}, @response=#<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>, @headers={"content-type"=>["application/xml"], "date"=>["Thu, 21 Jul 2016 14:26:07 GMT"], "server"=>["Apache/2.2.29 (Amazon)"], "x-powered-by"=>["PHP/5.3.28"], "content-length"=>["542"], "connection"=>["Close"]}>
```

Comment: Its likely that somewhere you're calling `xxx.code` where xxx is a hash, you should be calling `xxx[:code]`. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: yes @Yule i am calling `response.code` in my code, where i am making a post request. I have updated my question.

Comment: i tried as you suggested `xxx[:code]` but it returns `nil`, because there is no    such key in hash.

Comment: Please put a line `puts response.inspect` in the very beginning of `handle_response` method and share what will be printed.

Comment: @mudasobwa added the result for `response.inspect`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, you are mocking an [`HTTParty::Response`](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/lib/httparty/response.rb#L9). One way would be to mock it directly with only `code` and `parsed_response`:

```
let(:resp) do
  Struct.new(:code, :parsed_response).new(200, {"TwilioResponse"=>...})
end
```

Another way would be to instantiate a real `HTTParty::Response` with:

```
let(:resp) do
  HTTParty::Response.new(
    nil, 
    Struct.new(:code, :parsed_response)
          .new(200, {"TwilioResponse"=>...}), -> { ... }
  )
end
```

I would go with the first approach. Please note, that you probably will need to change in `handle_response`:

```
response_base = response['TwilioResponse']
```

to

```
response_base = response.parsed_response['TwilioResponse']
```

Comment: hey @mudasobwa thanks for reply. Yes the first way is better but i would like to use 2nd way. but i am getting an error `NoMethodError:
       undefined method 'body' for 200:Fixnum` , any help on that.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was in rush and posted an incomplete example. As you could see in the `HTTParty::Response#initialize` code I linked, the second parameter there is to be a response object. Please see an update. BTW, I see no reason here to use the 2nd approach, that’s why I was not too picky with re-checking it.

Comment: Hey well thanks, first approach worked. In second approach still getting the same error. Can you explain what's `-> { ... }` this argument is for.

Comment: I linked the code of `HTTParty::Response`’s constructor. What’s the problem to got there and look for all parameters? The third one is to be a `proc`, I do not care what is it for. I guessed there might be any `proc` instance passed, maybe I was wrong.

Comment: hey i was just asking, i don't have that much experience with httparty and rspec. Thanks buddy, your first approach worked like charm.

Comment: @mudasobwa - Why do you use a Struct instead of a double?

Comment: @BSeven for the sake of being as much pure Ruby as possible.

Comment: @mudasobwa - That makes sense. I had a feeling there was a good reason.

Comment: For some reason to satisfy `response.success?` My `resp` Struct needed to be: `Struct.new(:success?, :parsed_response).new(true, auth_response)` 

Where `auth_response` is another variable of the response body I wanted returned

Comment: 1 up because of the `parsed_response`. I was getting nuts trying to create a double for the response but always receiving `<InstanceDouble(HTTParty::Response) (anonymous)> received unexpected message :[]`